# If a random variable $X$ and its mapping $\mathrm{ln}(X+1)$ have the same distribution, what is the distribution of $X$?

Tags: probability, functional-equations

Let $f_X(x)$ be the probability density function of a real random variable $X$, $X\geq0$. Define $Y=\mathrm{ln}(X+1)$ and denote the PDF of $Y$ as $f_Y(y)$. I'm curious when will $f_X=f_Y$?

I've tried to use the [formula for functions of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables). The distribution $f_X$ seems need to satisfy: (call $f_X=f$ to save the subscript)
$$
f(x) = f(e^x-1)e^x \quad\quad x\geq0
$$
And the antiderivative $F$ of $f$ will satisfy:
$$
F(x)=F(e^x-1) \quad\quad x\geq0
$$
I was unable to solve the above equations. Could you please help me? I apologize if I made mistakes on the problem statement or the derivation.

Comment: One random variables that has this property is the degenerate random variable that is always zero. This doesn’t have a density, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I was unable to realize it so quickly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\ln(x+1) \le x$, with equality only at $x=0$.  For any $y > 0$, 
$$\mathbb P(X < y) = \mathbb P(\ln(X+1) < \ln(y+1)) = \mathbb P(X < \ln(y+1))$$
which says $\mathbb P(\ln(y+1) \le X < y) = 0$.  From that you can conclude that
$X = 0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! Although I understand each of your steps, I cannot reasoning like this by myself...